# SQL Delete similar Entries

Tags: sql, jdbc, derby

SQL Question.
I currently have two SQL tables One table called Waitlist and one Called Booking. They are not identical (waitlist contains more information than booking). They appear like so:

Waitlist:

```
#   Customer    Day                 Timestamp                   Flight
1   Joseph     2017-04-22      2017-04-22 16:20:33.178     F101
```

Booking:

```
#   Customer    Flight  Day
1   Timmy   F101    2017-04-22
2   Joseph  F101    2017-04-22
```

I would like to delete the duplicate data from waitlist (in this case the joseph entry).... I have tried the following:
DELETE FROM Waitlist WHERE Customer = booking.customer and day = booking.day and flight = booking.flight
I have also tried an INNER JOIN with no luck.
Please Help!!

Comment: `delete the duplicate data from waitlist` ... I only see a single record in `waitlist`.  By the way, which database are you using (e.g. MySQL, Oracle, etc.)?

Comment: I am using the Derby Database and JDBC. I apologize for not being clear in my question, I was wondering how I could delete the first and only entry in waitlist since I have it in Booking. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve your goal but the most appropriate answer to your question would be **database vendor specific**.

I.e. in both MySQL and SQL Server you can use `JOIN` directly in `DELETE` statement

```sql
DELETE w 
  FROM waitlist w JOIN booking b 
    ON w.customer = b.customer
   AND w.day = b.day
   AND w.flight = b.flight;
```

[Sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/830715/1) for MySql, [Sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/83071/1) for SQL Server

In PostgreSQL you can leverage `EXISTS`

```
DELETE FROM waitlist w
 WHERE EXISTS (
     SELECT *
       FROM booking
      WHERE customer = w.customer
        AND day = w.day
        AND flight = w.flight
);
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/1d754/1)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I am using a Derby Database and JDBC, I have tried the ways you mentioned and I still seem to be running into a syntax error SQLException.

Comment: Is there a unique id column in `waitlist` table? I'd guess `#` is not the name of the column...

Comment: I wasn't able to get the first answer to work, but the second one worked perfectly. Thank you for the help.